# Angular 8 - primeNG table - set all cells editable by default

Tags: angular, angular8, primeng-datatable

I didn't find any info about how t set all cells editable by default in template.

My template:

```
 <p-table
      #docDataTable
      [value]="dataValues.values"
      dataKey="id"
      [lazy]="true"
      [paginator]="false"
      [rows]="2"
      [totalRecords]=""
      [sortField]="'createdOn'"
      [sortOrder]="-1"
      scrollHeight="calc(100% - 10px)"
      [style]="{width:'100%'}"
      editMode="row"
      [responsive]="true"
      [columns]="tableColumns">

<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="tableColumns" let-editing="editing"
                   let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
  <tr [pEditableRow]="rowData">
<td *ngIf="dataValues" class="ellipsis" pEditableColumn>
            <p-cellEditor>
              <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                <editor
                  class="document-tag__editor"
                  [(ngModel)]="rowData.description"
                  [init]="{
                base_url: '/tinymce',
                suffix: '.min',
                inline: true,
                height: 500,
                menubar: false,
                toolbar:
                  'subscript superscript'
                }"></editor>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                {{removeAllHtmlTagsFromString(rowData.description) | truncateValue: 40}}
              </ng-template>
            </p-cellEditor>
          </td>
```

Is it possible? I don't want to click on a cell first to enable edit mode... Edit mode should be enabled by default... I know how to do that in component/programatically, but it works slowly:

```
this.dataValues.values.forEach(row => this.docDataTable.initRowEdit(row));
```

Answer (score 1):

From Prime NG documentation about Tables, in the Row Editing section. (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/table)

> Moreover, you may use setting pEditableRowDisabled property as true to
> disable editing for that particular row **and in case you need to
> display rows in edit mode by default, use the editingRowKeys property
> which is a map whose key is the dataKey of the record where the value
> is any arbitrary number greater than zero**.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it's an old question but I have the answer: maybe I can help next ones having the same problem.

The property editingRowKeys as pointed by Joe Mtz is the way: it's a map of (row) ids with a boolean value for editable (or not). So in your case, if your dataKey id is a string, and you have 'keyOne' and 'keyTwo' your code should be something like this

```
editingRowKeys: { [id: string]: boolean } = {}; 
editingRowKeys['keyOne'] = true;
editingRowKeys['keyTwo'] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@ViewChild**. Below code worked for me

**component.ts**

```
import { Table } from 'primeng/table';

@ViewChild(Table)
private dataTable!: Table;


public onRowEditInit(data:DataModel) {
        this.dataTable.editingRowKeys = {[data.id]:true}
}
```